# HTML-Entity escaping to prevent XSS

Tags: java, html, escaping, xss, owasp

I have some user input. Within my code, I ensure that the following symbols are escaped:

```
& -> &amp; 
< -> &lt; 
> -> &gt;
```

[OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_%28Cross_Site_Scripting%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#RULE_.231_-_HTML_Escape_Before_Inserting_Untrusted_Data_into_HTML_Element_Content) states that there are more chars to be escaped.

For attributes, I do another kind of escaping:

```
& -> &amp; 
" -> &quot;
```

This ensures that all attributes are enclosed by ". This makes me sure about my html-attributes, but not about HTML itself.

I wonder if my escaping is sufficient. I've read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2113984/is-replacing-and-with-lt-and-gt-enough-to-prevent-xss-injection), but I'm still not sure about my concern.

(JavaScripts are escaped with the OWASP-Library)

Comment: `' -> &apos;` and `% -> &perc;` (for XSS, encoding chars per %34 etc.)

Comment: @JoopEggen In what case would be replacing `%` by `&perc;` useful?

Comment: @Gumbo `&perc;` is indeed less useful against XSS, but it can obfuscate urls. Browsers do not take a % code for its char, i.e.: `<a href="%6Aavascript:alert('hi')">` does not invoke javascript.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I use the OWASP ([ESAPI](http://code.google.com/p/owasp-esapi-java/downloads/list)) library as well, to escape strings for different types of display, use :

```
String html = ESAPI.encoder().encodeForHTML("hello < how > are 'you'");
String html_attr = ESAPI.encoder().encodeForHTMLAttribute("hello < how > are 'you'");
String js = ESAPI.encoder().encodeForJavaScript("hello < how > are 'you'");
```

HTML (assume jsp)

```
<tag attr="<%= html_attr %>" onclick="alert('<%= js %>')"><%= html %></tag>
```

**Update** (*2017*)

As ESAPI Encoders are considered [legacy](https://github.com/OWASP/owasp-java-encoder#2014-01-30---version-111-released), a better alternative has been created and is actively being maintained, I would strongly recommend using the [OWASP Java Encoder](https://github.com/OWASP/owasp-java-encoder) instead.

If your project already uses `ESAPI`, an [integration](https://github.com/OWASP/owasp-java-encoder/blob/master/esapi/src/main/java/org/owasp/encoder/esapi/ESAPIEncoder.java) has been added that will allow you to use this library for encoding instead.

The usage is explained on their [wiki page](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Java_Encoder_Project#tab=Use_the_Java_Encoder_Project), but for the sake of completion, this is how you can use it to contextually encode your data:

```
// HTML Context
String html = Encoder.forHtml("u<ntrus>te'd'");

// HTML Attribute Context
String htmlAttr = Encoder.forHtmlAttribute("u<ntrus>te'd'");

// Javascript Attribute Context
String jsAttr = Encoder.forJavaScriptAttribute("u<ntrus>te'd'");
```

HTML (assume jsp)

```
<div data-attr="<%= htmlAttr %>" onclick="alert('<%= jsAttr %>')">
    <%= html %>
</div>
```

*PS:* more contexts exist and are supported by the library

Comment: As I mentioned, I use OWASP for escaping Javascript-Strings. But I have some legacy code, which is produced by apache cocoon. This code is doing the escaping as I described. My question is: Is that escaping sufficient? If not (and only if not) I will have to modify ~200 XSL-Stylesheet line by line.

Comment: imho, i do not think it is sufficient, just by checking this site (http://ha.ckers.org/xss.html) you can already determine that your escaping is not sufficient

Comment: @ckuetbach, does that answer your question?

Comment: I think my escaping should be enough. Attributes and Javascripts are escaped as described at OWASP. Only within pure HTML, my escaping is less hard than the OWASP says it should be. But at ha-ckers.org I can't fin any HTML-Body only XSS witch woul work if < and > are escaped.

Comment: **2014/2015 Update:** I would highly recommend using this as a reference for avoiding XSS attacks. It's by the OWASP people as well: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_%28Cross_Site_Scripting%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet

Comment: @PrestonBadeer yes i'm reading this now. can i ask you a ques about this article?. it says to escape the following characters. & --> &amp;
 < --> &lt;  
 > --> &gt;   
 " --> &quot;   
 ' --> &#x27;  
 / --> &#x2F;   I am using htmlspecialchars($string, ENT_QUOTES) to do this but it is not escaping the / should i do this manually? thanks for the help

Comment: @sarah ESAPI is a open source library that provides a function that is safer than using htmlspecialchars(). Their example in the link I posted is: `String safe = ESAPI.encoder().encodeForHTML( request.getParameter( "input" ) );`

Comment: @PrestonBadeer Cool thanks. so I might use that instead.. Is it the latest zip file here (released in sept 2013) that i should download?.. thanks https://code.google.com/p/owasp-esapi-java/downloads/list

Comment: @PrestonBadeer nevermind my question. I was looking for the javascript one and I've just found it here: https://code.google.com/archive/p/owasp-esapi-js/downloads for anyone else that is looking... thanks

Comment: @WillieScholtz : I WillieScholtz, I have gone through yours solution its really helpful but in my case I am directly doing attribute encding from attribut level in my jsp like `<input id="rlv" type="text" name="releaseVersion" maxlength="250" size="25" value="<%=$ESAPI.encoder().encodeForHTMLAttribute(request.getAttribute("relV"))%>" style="font-size:12px;font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif;"  onkeyup = "releaseVersionSearch();" onblink="releaseVersionSearch();"  class="modulecontent" />` when I am doing like this my page is not loading on browser

Comment: @WillieScholtz : And in browser console tab I able to see this error **net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING** can please help me what I am doing mistake here ? Ty.

Comment: @Venki, it would be best to ask a new question

Comment: @WillieScholtz : Sure Willie Schotz. Let me create new question for this. Ty.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend you to use Appache Common Lang library to escape strings, for exmaple to escape HTML:

```
String escapedString = org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml(String str);
```

the library has many useful methods to escape in HTML, XML, Javascript.

Comment: I don't think the common lang lib is tested for deliberately malicious input in the same way that ESAPI is.

Comment: Actually, StringEscapeUtils does not escape single-quote `'` into `&apos;`, so it is not suited for HTML escaping to prevent XSS