# Prevent xss attack while reading url content

Tags: java, xss

I am told reading from a web request without validating it can cause an XSS attack. How do I prevent this? How do I validate and encode the data before converting it into binary format. Any inputs will be appreciated as I am completely lost trying to figure this out.

```
boolean headerContent = false;
InputStream inputStream = null;
HttpURLConnection urlConn = null;
for (String key : keySet) {
if (key.equalsIgnoreCase("Content-Encoding") && value.equalsIgnoreCase("gzip")) {
    headerContent = true;
    continue;


 }  

} 

if (headerContent) {
    inputStream = new GZIPInputStream(urlConn.getInputStream());
   } else {
    inputStream = urlConn.getInputStream() ;
   }

   int readData;
   while ((readData = inputStream.read(bytes)) > 0) {
    outputStream.write(bytes, 0, readData);
}
```

Comment: XSS is dangerous for the browsers that use JavaScript. How can your app be affected ?

Comment: Moreover XSS has nothing to do with downloaded files. It resides inside webpages, not files

Comment: I am basically reading the content from a url and writing to an output stream without validating it. Before writing it out, I'd like to validate and encode the data before converting into binary format.

Comment: you mean you fetch a webpage from `inputStream` and redirect it somewhere else by `outputStream` ? what is that `outputStream` in your code associated with?

Comment: The output stream writes the url content into an output stream.

Comment: So where does the data go when you write it to output stream? Anyway, end-user might do some filtering stuff like wiping out all suspicious JavaScript fragments out of the page.

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8909613/html-entity-escaping-to-prevent-xss