# How do people bypass simple xss filters that replace the < with &lt;

Tags: javascript, xss

I coded a simple xss filter in javascript and I want to know of any simple xss that can get around it

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>Filter</title>
</head>
<body>
 <textarea style="width: 621px; height: 314px;"></textarea>
 <script>
  document.body.innerHTML += "<div><pre></pre></div>";
  document.addEventListener("keydown", function (e) {
   if(e.keyCode == 13) {
    window.localStorage.setItem("text", window.localStorage.getItem("text")+document.querySelector("textarea").value);
    window.localStorage.setItem("text", window.localStorage.getItem("text").replace(/</g, "&lt;"));
    document.querySelector("pre").innerHTML = window.localStorage.getItem("text");
   }
  })
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Only runs in external editor or html file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is replacing : < and > with &lt; and &gt; enough to prevent XSS injection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2113984/is-replacing-and-with-lt-and-gt-enough-to-prevent-xss-injection)

Answer (score 0):

If your input is reflected like `<p>PAYLOAD</p>` it might be hard, but if you find reflection in a html atribute like `<a src="PAYLOAD">` you can get xss by inputting `1" onerror="alert(document.cookie);"` if the aplication does not filter " or () this might result in stored xss